# Strictly increasing sequence $\{ a_k \}$ of positive integers such that $\sum 1/{a_k}$ is finite

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there a strictky increasing sequence $\{ a_k\}$  of positive integers such that $\sum 1/{a_k}$ is finite and minimal with respect to this property, in a sense that if $\{ b_k \}$ is another sequence of such, then $a_k \leq b_k$ for all but finitely many values of $k$?

Motivation came from comparing the series $\sum 1/n$ and $\sum 1/{n^2}$, the first of which is divergent but the second of which is not; the sequence for the first is "smaller" than that of the second.

If this question need be motified to make my question clearer, please comment/suggest adit as well.

Comment: If $\sum1/a_n$ converges there exists some positive sequence $(b_n)$ such that $b_n/a_n\to0$ and $\sum1/b_n$ converges. Hence, no, no minimal element, for deep reasons.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not such a minimizer. Suppose there were a sequence $\{a_k\}$ with the desired property. Clearly there must be a gap at some point, so there is an index $k_0$ such that

$$a_{k_0} > a_{k_0 - 1} + 1.$$

Otherwise, we would have the (divergent) harmonic series.

Now consider the sequence $b_k$ where $b_k = a_k$ for all $k \ne k_0$, and $b_{k_0} = a_{k_0} - 1$.

Comment: The answer is still no, and you can modify this example to show it. Take a (rapidly increasing) sequence of gaps, and subtract $1$ each time. Also, please do not substantially modify your question after it's already been answered.